# Is there a "built in way" to log everything with glog up to the program crash?

Tags: c++, logging

I'm interested in using some logging to help me detect potential problems in my code, and to detect where my program crashed. My problem is that lib that I used (google glog) doesn't log the stuff if they occur just before the program crash. So I tried to do something like this (this is template for 3 arguments):

```
mutex logMtx;
template<class T, class U, class V>
void mutexLOG_INFO(T t, U u, V v)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<t;
    ss<<u;
    ss<<v;
    LOG(INFO)<<ss.str();
    mutex::scoped_lock sl(logMtx);
    google::FlushLogFiles(0);
}
```

It works AFAIK (from my testing), but as you can see it is not very nice, because I need to do my own function for every level (INFO,WARNING..) and for every number of parameters. Also I hate reinventing the wheel.

So is there a way to tell glog to flush every time after LOG?

P.S. I know that this is g-log, not g-db (oops, name taken :) but I prefer to have the option to print nicely my STL data, I use gdb only to detect where things died.

EDIT: SO proves again that it is a great source of info:

```
#include <glog/logging.h>
#include <**gflags**/gflags.h>
...
FLAGS_logbuflevel=-1;
```

Comment: I recommend you use GDB and get a full stack trace upon crash to help find this. Debugging from a log is like debugging from printf's or couts. It is primitive, time-consuming, and often hides potential observations from you because you aren't looking in the appropriate area.

Comment: @San Jacinto - like I told you, in GDB my STL containers are unreadable.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl that doesn't change the fundamental shortcoming of the method you want to employ to debug a program, especially a concurrency-oriented program. But that said, it may work for you in this instance. By all means, do what you want to do. My suggestion is only that there are diminishing returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use gflags with glog and if you run --help the option logbuflevel might be what you are looking for.

```
    -logbuflevel (Buffer log messages logged at this level or lower (-1 means
  don't buffer; 0 means buffer INFO only; ...)) type: int32 default: 0
```

Comment: Absolutely not clear how to use this answer.

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham glog will "buffer" logs statements so you might not see the last few before the crash. I was just say you can add the flag "-logbuflever=-1" as a command line argument. Is that more clear?

Comment: Please provide more context for your answer. That is, how to use the gflags specification that you provide -i.e do I copy what you wrote into and HTML file? echo it into /dev/random? Enter it on the command line in ksh? As written, the current answer does not provide enough context to be usable except by someone who probably doesn't need to read it in the first place. Thanks.