# QProcess::readyReadStandardError() signal not emit until the process closed?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess, glog

I'm trying to redirect other process's stdout and stderr to my Qt GUI app. But I notice that QProcess::readyReadStandardError() signal only emitted (once) when the other process is closing.

Is there something wrong in my code?

```
void MainWindow::slotPreview()
{
    // ... other stuff...

    m_process = new QProcess(this);
    m_process->setWorkingDirectory(qApp->applicationDirPath());
    connect(m_process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(slotPreviewProcessHasStdOut()));
    connect(m_process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(slotPreviewProcessHasStdErr()));
    connect(m_process, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(slotPreviewProcessFinished()));
    m_process->start("executor.exe");
}

void MainWindow::slotPreviewProcessHasStdErr()
{
    ui->output->appendText(m_process->readAllStandardError());
}

void MainWindow::slotPreviewProcessHasStdOut()
{
    ui->output->appendText(m_process->readAllStandardOutput());
}

void MainWindow::slotPreviewProcessFinished()
{
    m_process->deleteLater();
    m_process = Q_NULLPTR;
}
```

In executor.exe app, I use google glog to log to stderr as below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);
    google::LogToStderr();
    {
    LOG(INFO) << "log started...";
    qDebug() << "qDebug started...";
    std::cout << "std::cout started..." << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "std::cerr started..." << std::endl;
    }
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    LOG(INFO) << "MainWindow displayed";
    return a.exec();
}
```

==============Update 1======================

Attach the output:

```
// before process closing:

std::cout started...
I0906 12:26:03.022691  3856 main.cpp:49] log started...
std::cerr started...

// when process is closing:
I0906 12:26:03.106772  3856 main.cpp:65] MainWindow displayed
```

It seems that:

1. statement `LOG(INFO) << "log started...";` is not flushed until statement `std::cerr << "std::cerr started..." << std::endl;` is about to execute.
2. output of statement `qDebug() << "qDebug started...";` is missing,

I have tried add `google::FlushLogFiles(google::GLOG_INFO);` after each LOG(INFO), did not fix the problem;

I have tried remove all other print statement except the LOG(INFO) one, did not fix the problem, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [logging with glog is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572073/logging-with-glog-is-not-working-properly)

Comment: Does it work as expected if you remove the google glog?

Comment: updated in original post